# How to align td elements in center

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created a simple table and want to align the td elements in center but align:center in css doesn't seem to work

```
.cTable td{
align:center;
}

<table border='1' id='mytable' class="cTable">
<tbody>
<tr><th>Claim ID</th><th>Status</th></tr> 
<tr><td align="center">22</td><td>333</td></tr>    
<tr><td>22</td><td>333</td></tr>
<tr><td>22</td><td>333</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It should be `text-align`, not `align`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-align

Comment: <td align="center">, align is not supported by html5, use css for solving this problem.

Answer (score 21):

What worked for me is the following (in view of the confusion in other answers):

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="radio" name="ageneral" value="male">
</td>
```

The proposed solution (`text-align`) works but must be used in a style attribute.

Comment: Why? :scratches-head:

Comment: This is incorrect. It can be used in a `<style>` element inside `<head>`, in a CSS file, or inserted via JavaScript... where does not matter.

Answer (score 5):

`margin:auto;`  text-align, if this won't work - try adding `display:block;` and set there `width:200px;` (in case your TD is too small).

Answer (score 4):

Give a style inside the `<td>` element or in your CSS file, like this:  `vertical-align: middle;`

Answer (score 0):

I personally didn't find any of these answers helpful. What worked in my case was giving the element `float:none` and `position:relative`. After that the element centered itself in the `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to center content in a table (for example `<video>` or `<img>`) is to do the following:

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="100%">
<tr>
<td>Video Tag 1 Here</td>
<td>Video Tag 2 Here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey there!  Your answer is missing the *reason* or *explanation* of why you feel this is the best way to achieve the result. Provide whatever insight and info you can, including links if you have any :)